# How to extract my geolocation (current position) coordinate using mapbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/dyGxwMm

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF4aW11czEzMTIiLCJhIjoiY2s4bXU2bWp2MDVkdDNucDNvOTc2MHdueCJ9.ilwrzH23r2G3_pfxaJn6IQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
    zoom: 3 // starting zoom
});                                      


// Add geolocate control to the map.
map.addControl(
    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        trackUserLocation: true
    })
);
```

**Click the top right corner of map to view your location.**

This is the demo of my code. I want to console.log() ,y current position. How to do that? I will give you my upvote if you have the ability to show your complete demo just like mine.Or else,.....

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
  zoom: 3, // starting zoom
});

// Add geolocate control to the map.
const geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
  },
  trackUserLocation: true,
});

map.addControl(geolocate);
// Set an event listener that fires
// when a geolocate event occurs.
geolocate.on('geolocate', function (ev) {
  console.log(ev.coords); // you'll get the coordinates
});
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/sako_me/pen/MWKNZVJ

Comment: Already did. Btw, are you familiar with Gmail Api using Javascript? Probably just need a little help